# How to create a single function that handles checkbox selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm working on this simple checkbox selection that works just fine when selecting a single row or selecting all the rows. However, I would like to have only one function that handles the checkbox selection. As of right now I have 3 functions called: customer_name_func , customer_lastname_func and customer_email_func. Can someone help me on this please? Here's my code that works just fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#checkAll").change(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    $(customer_name_func);
    $(customer_lastname_func);
    $(customer_email_func);
  });

  var customer_name_func = function() {
    if ($("#customer-name-checkbox").is(":checked")) {
      $('#customer-name-inputField').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#customer-name-inputField').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  };
  $(customer_name_func);
  $("#customer-name-checkbox").change(customer_name_func);

  var customer_lastname_func = function() {
    if ($("#customer-lastname-checkbox").is(":checked")) {
      $('#customer-lastname-inputField').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#customer-lastname-inputField').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  };
  $(customer_lastname_func);
  $("#customer-lastname-checkbox").change(customer_lastname_func);

  var customer_email_func = function() {
    if ($("#customer-email-checkbox").is(":checked")) {
      $('#customer-email-inputField').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#customer-email-inputField').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  };
  $(customer_email_func);
  $("#customer-email-checkbox").change(customer_email_func);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />Select All
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="customer-name-checkbox" name="customer-name-checkbox" value="yes">
  <!---echo php customerName value from WS--->
  <label for="pizza">Name&nbsp;&nbsp; LastName&nbsp;&nbsp; Phone Number</label>
  <input type="email" name="name" id="customer-name-inputField" />
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <input type="checkbox" id="customer-lastname-checkbox" name="customer-lastname-checkbox" value="yes">
  <!---echo php customerLastName value from WS--->
  <label for="pizza">Name&nbsp;&nbsp; LastName&nbsp;&nbsp; Phone Number</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="customer-lastname-inputField" />
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <input type="checkbox" id="customer-email-checkbox" name="customer-email-checkbox" value="yes">
  <!---echo php customerPhoneNumber value from WS--->
  <label for="pizza">Name&nbsp;&nbsp; LastName&nbsp;&nbsp; Phone Number</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="customer-email-inputField" />
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: FYI, inside `$(document).ready()` you don't need to use `$(functionName)`, just call the functions normally: `functionName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use HTML-5 `data-*` attribute to store custom information on the element.

   Add `data-target` attribute on each checkbox and the value of this attribute should be the corresponding textbox ID

   ```
   data-target="customer-name-inputField" name="customer-name-checkbox" value="yes"
   ```
2. Add a common class to all the checkboxes.

   ```
   class="myCheckbox"
   ```
3. Bind events on all the checkboxes using the common class.

   ```
   $('.myCheckbox').change(function() {
   ```
4. Inside event handler use `$(this)` and `data()` to get the elements `data-*` attribute value.

   ```
   $(this).data('target')
   ```
5. Use `trigger('change')` to trigger the change event on the checkboxes.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#checkAll").change(function() {
    $('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', this.checked).trigger('change');
  });

  $('.myCheckbox').change(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('target')).prop('disabled', !this.checked);
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />Select All

    <input type="checkbox" id="customer-name-checkbox" data-target="customer-name-inputField" name="customer-name-checkbox" value="yes" class="myCheckbox">
    <label for="pizza">Name&nbsp;&nbsp; LastName&nbsp;&nbsp; Phone Number</label>
    <input type="email" name="name" id="customer-name-inputField" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="customer-lastname-checkbox" data-target="customer-lastname-inputField" name="customer-lastname-checkbox" value="yes" class="myCheckbox">
    <label for="pizza">Name&nbsp;&nbsp; LastName&nbsp;&nbsp; Phone Number</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="customer-lastname-inputField" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="customer-email-checkbox" data-target="customer-email-inputField" name="customer-email-checkbox" value="yes" class="myCheckbox">
    <!---echo php customerPhoneNumber value from WS--->
    <label for="pizza">Name&nbsp;&nbsp; LastName&nbsp;&nbsp; Phone Number</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="customer-email-inputField" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a single function that operates on a checkbox, getting the ID of the input field by modifying its own name. Give all the checkboxes that need this a class so you can operate on them all with `.each()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#checkAll").change(function() {
    $(".input_checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).each(function() {
        enable_disable_input(this);
    });
  });

  function enable_disable_input(checkbox) {
    var input_id = checkbox.id.replace('-checkbox', '-inputField');
    $("#" + input_id).prop('disabled', !checkbox.checked);
  }

  $(".input_checkbox").change(function() {
    enable_disable_input(this);
  });

  $(".input_checkbox").each(function() {
    enable_disable_input(this);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />Select All
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox" name="customer-name-checkbox" value="yes">
  <!---echo php customerName value from WS--->
  <label for="pizza">Name&nbsp;&nbsp; LastName&nbsp;&nbsp; Phone Number</label>
  <input type="email" name="name" id="customer-name-inputField" />
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <input type="checkbox" id="customer-lastname-checkbox" class="input_checkbox" name="customer-lastname-checkbox" value="yes">
  <!---echo php customerLastName value from WS--->
  <label for="pizza">Name&nbsp;&nbsp; LastName&nbsp;&nbsp; Phone Number</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="customer-lastname-inputField" />
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <input type="checkbox" id="customer-email-checkbox" class="input_checkbox" name="customer-email-checkbox" value="yes">
  <!---echo php customerPhoneNumber value from WS--->
  <label for="pizza">Name&nbsp;&nbsp; LastName&nbsp;&nbsp; Phone Number</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="customer-email-inputField" />
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```